# Index PDFs using Lucene, NoSuchFieldError

Tags: pdf, lucene, nosuchfieldexception

I'm trying to index PDF files using Apache Lucene 4.4

I keep getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TOKENIZED
at com.snowtide.pdf.lucene.LuceneInterface20.addField(SourceFile:18)
at com.snowtide.pdf.lucene.PDFDocumentFactory.buildPDFDocument(SourceFile:174)
at com.snowtide.pdf.lucene.PDFDocumentFactory.buildPDFDocument(SourceFile:84)
at com.apache.lucene.search.EasyLuceneIntegration.addPDFToIndex(EasyLuceneIntegration.java:134)
at com.apache.lucene.search.EasyLuceneIntegration.main(EasyLuceneIntegration.java:62)
```

I'm using PDFTextStream and following their example in here:
[enter link description here](http://snowtide.com/help/indexing-pdf-documents-with-lucene-and-pdftextstream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project you've referenced only supports up to Lucene 2.2.  I'd recommend looking into [tika](/questions/tagged/tika), to get your PDFs into an acceptable format, or you can just use [pdfbox](/questions/tagged/pdfbox) (which, I believe, is the package Tika uses for PDFs).